# How to create Class<> and how does it work exactly?

Tags: c#, list, generics

How are this kind of classes created:

```
List<string> example = new List<string>();
```

Comment: you need to read some tutorials & books about _generics_ and _arrays_

Comment: Begin with [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) and then [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a generic class of type T. When you instantiate the object from the class, that is where you specify what type T will take.

Here is a [page on MSDN describing generic classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

An example:

```
public class MyClass<T> 
{
    private List<T> MyList;

    public MyClass(List<T> list) 
    {
        this.MyList = list;
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return MyList[i];
        }
        set
        {
            MyList[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on this[] you can look at [Indexers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx). These allow you to use the class with the square bracket notation, as you might with an array.

When you use the class, that is where you decide what type T will be. See the following:

```
MyClass<string> myStrings = new MyClass<string>(new List<string> { "hello" });

myStrings[0] = "change the 0th element";

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Element 0 is {0}", myStrings[0]));
```

To make it **multidimensional**, here is an example of how you would change it:

```
private List<List<T>> MyList;

public T this[int a, int b]
{
    get { return MyList[a][b]; }
    set { MyList[a][b] = value; }
}
```

You can then use the accessor/mutator like this:

```
myObject[1,3] = "a new string at row 1, column 3";

Console.WriteLine(myObject[0,4]);
```

Comment: thanks, ... no wander I couldn't find answer with searching if everybody just down votes everything with potential knowledge. probably there will be bunch of people asking same thing as they can't find my question nor your answer, ...

Comment: @MilitaryG, people are downvoting because your question is a little bit confusing.

Comment: @MilitaryG, you were also wondering about how to make something that is multidimensional. I have updated the answer to include an example of this.

Comment: so I guess this is better? Showing I did not try doing no effort, ... and thanks @Will Newton for quick example, ... even if I could find my own way of doing 1 multi dimentional, ...